# How to merge rows into single column using FOR XML PATH in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, for-xml-path

I want to **merge rows into single column** using `FOR XML PATH` in `SQL`.

Here is my Query:

```
select d.Device from tbl_Sales_OrderItems tsoi left join tbl_devices d 
on d.DeviceID=tsoi.DeviceID
where salesorderid=102 
and tsoi.Quantity>0
and tsoi.TypeID=1

union all

select d.Partnumber Device from tbl_Sales_OrderItems tsoi left join tbl_VendorParts d 
on d.VendorPartID=tsoi.RefID
where salesorderid=102 
and tsoi.Quantity>0
and tsoi.TypeID=2
```

Here i am getting two rows i.e Two Device name in from `tbl_Sales_Order`.

*Now these rows i want to get in single row using `FOR XML PATH` into a single column.*

Further after applying `FOR XML PATH` i want to use it in `select query` i want to use the row value which would be as follows.

```
Select salesorderid,@resultinRow from tbl_Sales_Orders
```

**Output Required:**

```
SalesOrderID  Devices
  102          Device1,Device2
  103          Device3,Device2
```

Answer (score 3):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (SalesOrderID INT, Devices VARCHAR(30))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
(102,'Device1'),
(102,'Device2'),
(103,'Device3'),
(103,'Device2')
```

**Query**

```
SELECT t.SalesOrderID
      , STUFF(( SELECT ', ' + Devices
                FROM @TABLE 
                WHERE SalesOrderID = t.SalesOrderID
                FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
                .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'') AS Devices
FROM @TABLE t
GROUP BY t.SalesOrderID
```

**Result Set**

```
╔══════════════╦══════════════════╗
║ SalesOrderID ║     Devices      ║
╠══════════════╬══════════════════╣
║          102 ║ Device1, Device2 ║
║          103 ║ Device3, Device2 ║
╚══════════════╩══════════════════╝
```

Comment: hi @M.Ali as i mentioned their are two different tables from where the Device name have to be selected tbl_Devices & tbl_VendorParts depending upon TypeID and also their are many columns so cant use GroupBy. Can you Please help me in existing query?